# How do you reply this letter in a formal way?

Tags: formality, letter-writing

**Hi Ryan,**

**We refer to our conversation on 30 January 2017, you have mentioned that it is not your usual practice to throw away the washing dryer without consulting us.**

**Please clarify.**

How am I suppose to reply to this email? Seems like they misunderstood me that we will consult them before throwing away the things. If I replied

**"It is indeed not our usual practice to throw away"**

this will make it as if I'm the one in the wrong here.. How am I suppose to reply? I want to say that we been doing this for a long time but we will ensure that this will not happen again.

Comment: Concentrate on what you want to say to them, not on what they said to you. (If you say it is not your usual practice, they will ask you why you did it now.) If you mostly want to apologize, say "I am sorry for my mistake and can assure you it will not happen further. Again, my apologies."

Comment: appreciated for your help, I was focusing too much on what they said to you hence stressing myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to say you usually throw away washing dryers without consultation, and do not think that this is wrong in any way,  but are happy to consult them in future, now that you have been asked, you could say:

> I am sorry for any confusion in our conversation of 30th January. In fact, it has been our usual practice not to consult before throwing away washing driers. However, now that we are aware of your concern  we will, of course, consult you in future.

This, I think, is clear that you did nothing unusual or wrong in throwing away the washing dryer, but are willing to do as requested in future.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sound apologetic, but not overly apologetic. I would respond as follows:

> That has indeed been my practice, but I was unaware that I was violating any rules. Moving forward, it won't happen again, and I'll be sure to consult you first in the future.